# Choose Which Conflicting Entry to Keep in a View

Tags: sqlite

Say that I have a Sqlite table like this:

```
Name       |Date of Appointment |Time of Appointment
------------------------------------------------
Jane Doe   |May 1st, 2013       |09:00
Jane Doe   |May 1st, 2013       |15:00
John Doe   |May 2nd, 2013       |08:00
John Doe   |May 3rd, 2013       |12:00
```

In the example, Jane Doe had two appointments on the same day, but John Doe had two different appointments on different days.

Now let's say I want to create a table view that shows all of the appointments on a particular day. I could create a view for May 1st using the following syntax:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS [May 1st Appointments] AS SELECT * FROM AppointmentsTable WHERE [Date of Appointment] = 'May 1st, 2013';
```

This creates a view that looks like the following:

```
Name       |Date of Appointment |Time of Appointment
------------------------------------------------
Jane Doe   |May 1st, 2013       |09:00
Jane Doe   |May 1st, 2013       |15:00
```

However, seeing multiple appointments for Jane Doe can look confusing, so I just want to display the most recent in the view. I see that I can use the [ON CONFLICT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) clause, but it seems that I always have to either keep the first entry and ignore the second, replace the first entry with the second, or halt the SQLite query.

Is there a way that I can choose which conflicting entry to keep in a view based on some conditional (like the most recent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'am correct what you want is the latest appointment for a particular date if there exists more than one appointment for a particular date

Then kindly try the query below it should work

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS [May 1st Appointments] AS SELECT * FROM AppointmentsTable a where [Date of Appointment] = 'May 1st, 2013' and [Time of Appointment]=(select [Time of Appointment] from AppointmentsTable where Name= a.Name and [Date of Appointment] = 'May 1st, 2013' order by [Time of Appointment] desc limit 1)
```

Comment: This solution definitely solves the problem. I hadn't considered creating an ordered subquery and limiting the results to one.